# how to find exactly data between selected diagonal area in mysql query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[image]

These are my coordinates of Selected diagonal points, will be more when selected points are more.

```
1: 25.312063043186914  2: 55.30672073364258
1: 25.24096949112138   2: 55.40525436401367
1: 25.224509592006314  2: 55.3462028503418
1: 25.22513076073063   2: 55.281314849853516
1: 25.27822894908031   2: 55.25899887084961
```

below is my current mysql query not giving me perfect result between selected diagonal.any help??

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  tbl_custom 
WHERE latitude <= 25.312063043186914 
  AND latitude >= 25.224509592006314 
  AND longitude <= 55.40525436401367 
  AND longitude >= 55.25899887084961
```

Comment: That should work, are you using the correct mysql type? DECIMAL(total digits,decimals)

Comment: yes, my mysql datatype  for latitude and longitude field is Decimal, i m getting result but it is also making marker out of my selected diagonal points?

Comment: Have a look to the [point-in-polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) problem. It is not so easy to code ;-) Postgres has predefined [functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html) for that. maybe mysql has them too.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the problem, but all your SQL will currently give you is any point which is inside a rectangular area defined by the diagonally-opposite corners (25.224509592006314,55.25899887084961) - (25.312063043186914,55.40525436401367).  So looking at your screenshot above, I picture that as a rectangle that completely encompasses your polygon, so could lead to a lot of false positives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To eliminate the points within your bounding box query but not within polygon you require to use [**Point in Polygon**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) algorithm.

The easiest way to do this is to have the coordinates in arrays. These can be used to find max and min coordinates for the query and for parameters for pointInPolygon() function.

```
function pointInPolygon(polySides,polyX,polyY,x,y) {
 var j = polySides-1 ;
  oddNodes = 0;
  for (i=0; i<polySides; i++) {
    if (polyY[i]<y && polyY[j]>=y  ||  polyY[j]<y && polyY[i]>=y) {
        if (polyX[i]+(y-polyY[i])/(polyY[j]-polyY[i])*(polyX[j]-polyX[i])<x)  {
            oddNodes=!oddNodes; 
        }
    }
   j=i; }

  return oddNodes;
}
```

In your Map code using [**jQuery getJSON()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
var polySides = 4;//number of points in polygon
//horizontal Latitude coordinates of polygon  
var polyLat = new Array();
polyLat[0] = 51.5;
polyLat[1] = 51.5;
polyLat[2] = 52.5;
polyLat[3] = 53;
polyLat[4] = 51.5;//First point repeated to close polygon
//vertical Longitude coordinates of polygon 
var polyLng =  new Array();
polyLng[0] = 0.5;
polyLng[1] = -1.9;
polyLng[2] = -1;
polyLng[3] = 0.6;
polyLng[4] = 0.5;
//Coordinates for bounding box
var maxLat = Math.max.apply(null,polyLat);
var minLat = Math.min.apply(null,polyLat);
var maxLng = Math.max.apply(null,polyLng);
var minLng = Math.min.apply(null,polyLng);

//Using jQuery
var url = "yourFile .php";
 url +="?maxLat="+maxLat +"&minLat="+minLat +"&maxLng="+maxLng +"&minLng="+minLng;
 $.getJSON(url,function(data) {
    $.each(data.marker,function(i,dat){
        if (pointInPolygon(polySides,polyLat,polyLng,dat.lat,dat.lng)){
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(dat.lat,dat.lng); 
            addMarker(latlng,dat.name);
            bounds.extend(latlng);
        }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
```

Map obtained using Bounding Box and Point in Polygon.

[image: pointin]

Comment: ,can you please show the php file,how did you do the query.Thanks