# Get coordinates inside circumference sector

Tags: sql, postgresql, geolocation, geo, geometry-shader

I have a database(PostgreSQL) with coordinates of lightning bolts. 
I want coordinates inside a circumference sector(SQL Query). I have the radius, angle(Z) and point A of circumference, and coordinates of extremal points([lat1,lng1], [lat2, lng2]).

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you coordinates of point A & radius?

Comment: Yes! i have coordinates of point A and radious of circumference

Comment: Have a look at my [**Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538063/how-to-find-exactly-data-between-selected-diagonal-area-in-mysql-query/20563777#20563777) to a similar Question. I will get back to you shortly with an answer.

Comment: [**See**](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/polygon/MapPolygonArc.html) for implementation using Spherical Law of Cosines Query and Point in Polygon Algorithm with php/MySQL