# PHP comparing longitude/latitude boundry coordinates to point

Tags: php

I opened up a shape file and converted it into a bunch of arrays. It contains longitude/latitude coordinates that make up the shape of a country:

> -69.996937629 12.577582098, -69.936390754 12.531724351, -69.924672004 12.519232489, -69.915760871 12.497015692, -69.88019772 12.453558661, -69.876820442 12.427394924, -69.888091601 12.417669989, -69.908802864 12.417792059, -69.930531379 12.42597077, -69.945139127 12.440375067, -69.924672004 12.440375067, -69.924672004 12.447211005, -69.958566861 12.463202216, -70.027658658 12.522935289, -70.04808509 12.53115469, -70.058094856 12.537176825, -70.062408007 12.54682038, -70.060373502 12.556952216, -70.051096158 12.574042059, -70.048736132 12.583726304, -70.052642382 12.600002346, -70.05964108 12.614243882, -70.061105924 12.625392971, -70.048736132 12.632147528, -70.007150845 12.585516669, -69.996937629 12.577582098

I would like to use these coordinates to figure out where users are located (country, region, city). Lets say I get a set of two coordinates from the client `xx.xxxxxxx` and `yy.yyyyyyy`, how can I compare the clients coordinates to the boundary coordinates using PHP? I don't know where to even start.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a duplicate of [Check if geolocation is within boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23300992/check-if-geolocation-is-within-boundaries)

If so then the accepted answer will help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23302866/6288186