# how do I track if user passess the boundary(geofencing)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I click in a certain location of map and plot markers on it and get the latlang coordinates and save it to my database as  boundary of my tracker.

this is the sample coordinates that i plot marker on my map and save it to database.

```
53.198526418064645,-105.76238214969635
53.198564980328875,-105.76508045196533
53.199002016899044,-105.76231241226196
53.19939406061905,-105.76508045196533
53.19941012790812,-105.76509118080139
53.19941976827867,-105.76212465763092
53.199426195191194,-105.76357841491699
```

Now I want that if the user(tracker) passess each coordinate  it will prompt like this, the user "get's in" or "get's out" in the area.but i have no idea how do i achieve like this to detect if the user passes or get inside in each coordinates or inside in my polygon.is this possible?

just like in gmaps 
[gmaps geofencing](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/geofences.html)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538063/how-to-find-exactly-data-between-selected-diagonal-area-in-mysql-query/20563777#20563777) may help

Comment: @davidstrachan,can you please show your php file ,in your example i have no idea how did you deal with in server side.

Comment: @davidstrachan,how do i checked if my tracker has this position,53.199278,-105.767054,meaning his not yet in the boundary or he get's out?