# draw polygon but it draws a line on center

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I draw polygon on my map but i get trouble because it draws a line on center if i formed a square or any shapes.I don't know what makes my polygon draw lines on center.

```
var map;  
  var count=0;
  var polycolor = '#ED1B24';
  var polyarray=[];
function initialize() {


            var initial = new google.maps.LatLng(53.199246241276875, -105.76864242553711);

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: initial,
                zoomControl: true,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
                },
                mapTypeControl: false
            };

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
                polyarray[count]= e.latLng;
                addPolygon(polyarray);
                count++;
            });


        }

 function addPolygon(path){

         var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
               path: path,
               strokeColor: polycolor,
               strokeOpacity: 1.0,
               strokeWeight: 2
           });

             poly.setMap(map);

       }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

here is my jsfiddle

[my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jemz24/BV3Js/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a line down the center, you are drawing a new polygon for each click.

Make the polygon global, and *update* the path each time you add a point to it:

```
var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
           strokeColor: polycolor,
           strokeOpacity: 1.0,
           strokeWeight: 2
    });

function addPolygon(path){
         poly.setPath(path);          
         poly.setMap(map);
   }
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BV3Js/9/)

Comment: can i ask also help on my other thread.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729643/how-do-i-track-if-user-passess-the-boundarygeofencing