# Marker on Point in polygon not displaying

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I want to display marker inside the polygon like this example that i followed.

[Point in polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538063/how-to-find-exactly-data-between-selected-diagonal-area-in-mysql-query/20563777#20563777)

But the marker did not show up.I think there is missing in my code,this is the coordinates that i saved to my database.

```
53.198524,-105.762383
53.198566,-105.765083
53.199001,-105.762314
53.199394,-105.765083
53.199409,-105.765091
53.199421,-105.762123
53.199425,-105.763580
```

I appreciate someone can help me to figure it out on how to get this work.

```
        var map;
        var polySides = 7;
        var polyLat  = new Array();

        polyLat[0]=53.198524;
        polyLat[1]=53.198566;
        polyLat[2]=53.199001;
        polyLat[3]=53.199394;
        polyLat[4]=53.199409;
        polyLat[5]=53.199421;
        polyLat[6]=53.199425;
        polyLat[7]=53.198524;


        var polyLng =  new Array();

        polyLng[0]=-105.762383;
        polyLng[1]=-105.765083;
        polyLng[2]=-105.762314;
        polyLng[3]=-105.765083;
        polyLng[4]=-105.765091;
        polyLng[5]=-105.762123;
        polyLng[6]=-105.763580;
        polyLng[7]=-105.762383;



        var maxLat = Math.max.apply(null,polyLat);
        var minLat = Math.min.apply(null,polyLat);
        var maxLng = Math.max.apply(null,polyLng);
        var minLng = Math.min.apply(null,polyLng);

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds;
      function initialize() {

            initial = new google.maps.LatLng(53.199246241276875,-105.76864242553711);

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: initial,
                zoomControl: true,
                zoomControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
                },
                mapTypeControl: false


            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

        }



    $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                  type:'post',
                  dataType:'json',
                  data:'maxLat='+maxLat +'&minLat='+minLat +'&maxLng='+maxLng +'&minLng='+minLng,
                  url:'polygeofence.php',
                  success: function(data){

                      bounds  = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                      $.each(data,function(i,dat){

                                 if (pointInPolygon(polySides,polyLat,polyLng,dat.lat,dat.lng)){
                                       var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(dat.lat),parseFloat(dat.lng));

                                      addMarker(latlng);
                                      bounds.extend(latlng);

                                  }

                      });
                      map.fitBounds(bounds);

                  }

            });
        });


     function pointInPolygon(polySides,polyX,polyY,x,y) {
            var j = polySides-1 ;
            oddNodes = 0;
            for (i=0; i<polySides; i++) {
                if (polyY[i]<y && polyY[j]>=y  ||  polyY[j]<y && polyY[i]>=y) {
                    if (polyX[i]+(y-polyY[i])/(polyY[j]-polyY[i])*(polyX[j]-polyX[i])<x)  {
                        oddNodes=!oddNodes;
                    }
                }
                j=i;
            }

            return oddNodes;
        }

     function addMarker(latlng){
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                draggable: false

            });
          marker.setMap(map);
     }







        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

php code

```
   $minlat = $_POST['minLat'];
   $maxlat = $_POST['maxLat'];
   $minlng = $_POST['minLng'];
   $maxlng = $_POST['maxLng'];

   $queryresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM geofencetbl WHERE
                    (lat>='$minlat' AND lat<='$maxlat')
                    AND (lng>='$minlng' AND lng<='$maxlng')
                  ");






 $results = array(
      'lat' => array(),
      'lng' => array(),
  );

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($queryresult,MYSQL_BOTH)){
      $results['lat'][] =$row['lat'];
      $results['lng'][] =$row['lng'];


  }




   echo  json_encode($results);
```

Edit:after edited my code,I have problem on my sucess dat.lat and dat.lng are undefined

Comment: At a guess I'd say the coordinates you're receiving back via AJAX are being treated as strings by Javascript.  Google Maps expects the values passed to the LatLng constructor to be numeric.  Try wrapping them in parseFloat: `var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(dat.lat), parseFloat(dat.lng));`

Comment: @duncan,i tried your solution but still no marker display

Comment: What if you `console.log(latlng)` in `addMarker()` function?

Comment: @MrUpsidown,
   
 
lat
 
 ["53.199394", "53.198566", "53.199409", 2 more...]
 
0
 
 "53.199394"
 
1
 
 "53.198566"
 
2
 
 "53.199409"
 
3
 
 "53.199425"
 
4
 
 "53.199001"
 
lng
 
 ["-105.765083", "-105.765083", "-105.765091", 2 more...]
 
0
 
 "-105.765083"
 
1
 
 "-105.765083"
 
2
 
 "-105.765091"
 
3
 
 "-105.763580"
 
4
 
 "-105.762314"

Comment: @MrUpsidown,I only have 7 lat and 7 lng in console.log(latlng)

Comment: Something must be wrong. `console.log(latlng)` should log a LatLng object. Not separate values like that. Something like `R {k: 53.198524, B: -105.762383, toString: function, j: function, equals: function…}`

Comment: @MrUpsidown,Did i miss something in my code?I don't know why it is not returning latLng Object...and it should many marker just like the example that i followed..I wonder why,where did i get wrong?

Comment: Do we have your complete code above? Did you not declare the same variable twice by any chance? Try to create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that reproduces the problem so that we can have a better look at it.

Comment: @MrUpsidown,those code above are the same with my code here at me.do i need still to create jsfiddle?

Comment: okay i will just create,please wait for a minute

Comment: @MrUpsidown,here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jemz24/x7hVf/39/

Comment: @MrUpsidown,those polyLng Array and polyLat Array are the same value  here in my geofencetbl table I only have 7 coordinates saved.the one in my php code.

Comment: @MrUpsidown,i forgot to include the jquery library..here is the updated http://jsfiddle.net/jemz24/x7hVf/41/

Answer (score 1):

Quite a lot of issues in your code. You are missing many variables declarations, and other stuff.

I commented most of my changes like that:

```
// missing bounds object here
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

I removed the AJAX part since of course it is not going to work. I am just creating one marker. No polygon. But at least this shows you that a correct LatLng object is passed to the `addMarker()` function.

Hope this helps!

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/aP3gs/)</kbd>

**Edit:**

Here is how you should create your JSON output.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM geofencetbl WHERE (lat>='$minlat' AND lat<='$maxlat') AND (lng>='$minlng' AND lng<='$maxlng')";

$result = $db->query($sql) or die($db->error);

while ($obj = $result->fetch_object()) {

    $results[] = $obj;
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

Then in your AJAX success function, log `dat` and you should understand how to deal with it!

Comment: the response of ajax is like this, 
lat
 
 ["53.199394", "53.198524", "53.198566", 4 more...]
 
lng
 
 ["-105.765083", "-105.762383", "-105.765083", 4 more...]

Comment: my dat.lat is undefined in my success ajax

Comment: i put marker on data like this  $.each(data.marker,function(i,dat),the map loads but there are no markers display

Comment: What about `var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(dat.lat[i],dat.lng[i]);`?

Comment: i put console.log("latlng",latlng);but it did not executed,also i remove back the data.marker,becuase jquery will get error "a is undefined",so i get back to  $.each(data.marker,function(i,dat)

Comment: The map will not load properly turns to blue it did not goes to the center which i initialize the map

Comment: It did not goes to my if statement after $.each(data,function(i,dat){..it tried to put console.log("dat.lat",dat.lat)it prints->undefined

Comment: Why add more complexity to your code before fixing the actual code? The way you construct your JSON is not good. I don't know why you would create these 2 arrays. See my updated answer.

Comment: So? `dat.lat` and `dat.lng` should hold what you need. `var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(dat.lat,dat.lng);`

Comment: Remove your `if` statement and please try to debug by yourself.

Comment: the polyLat array like 51.5,51.5..and the polyLng 0.5,etc..in the example link i posted above,are they are in the database?that he querried using getJSON ?

Comment: Are you asking that to me? What getJSON? If you take data from the db you don't need these arrays, do you?

Comment: No i am not asking about the getJson,I am asking if those arrays he created polyLat and polyLang are the same coordinates in his db?

Comment: You are the one who asked the question. Now you are asking if *he* did this or that? Who is *he*?! Anyway I see no point to this question at all.

Comment: The link that i posted above "Point in Polygon",the one who answer the thread is "david strachan"

Comment: Oh all right. I would guess these are the values in the db that he put in an array for the demo. I edited my answer with a PHP example. Does that not suit what you need?

Comment: I thinks your php example is work fine with me,but the problem is that only one marker is created in the map i thinks it's in my code.I am still debugging my code.